# Full screen with action bar Support lib - Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am using the support v7 lib as I am developing an app which will support API 10 and above. My app is fullscreen mode and landscape. So I am using the theme:
`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"`
 I want an action bar as well. How can i achieve that?
I am using this code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR); // Add this line
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.show();
```

But its not working as the line `ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();` gives the error:

```
Incompatible types.
Required : android.support.v7.app.ActionBar
Found : android.app.ActionBar
```

But I have imported correctly : `import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;` 

What's wrong? Please help me!

And then I want to overlay the action bar as mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html):. I know it can be done as the android gallery app has it.

```
<resources>
<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
       parent="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> But its not working as the line ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar(); gives the error:

Call the support ActionBar with this line:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```